# What is method Descriptor/signature for byte[] byte array using JNI?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

My JAVA class code snippet. I want to access getReg_chal() method from my C file using JNI:

```
public byte[] getReg_chal() {
    return reg_chal;
}
```

My C file doing some jni operation:

```
mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, info, "getReg_chal()", "([B)V");

mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, info, "getReg_chal()", ***);
```

I want to know the method descriptor for my byte[]. Writing `"({B)V"` gives me method not found error. What would I fill in ***?
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get `"({B)V"` from, and why did you think it would work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[B**

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp9502

Comment: Debugging hint: search your Android project folder, open bin/com folder, somewhere inside you'll find compiled .class files from your java sources.
Use tool such as Total Commander to view the class file (F3 - lister), although it is binary file, you'll see some texts there. Find text of your method name getReg_chal. Right next to it you should see its jni signature. Copy/paste from there and you're done.

Comment: It should be "()[B" in your case.

Comment: @mice: better yet, use "javap -s ClassName" to get all the signatures nicely printed to stdout :)

Comment: Maybe you can help me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/56579045/5709159 Thanks in advance