# How to invoke specific Java method from NDK(JNI)?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am fresh in this topic.

I use NDK in my Android app and I have such method in Java

```
static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```

Now I need to use this method from NDK

Actually I wrote something like this

```
jbyteArray arr = env->CallStaticByteMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.get_bytes, image_obj);
```

But problem is `CallStaticByteMethod` return type `jbyte`, but I need `jbyteArray`...

So, question how to write this method?

**EDIT**

```
jobject arr_obj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.get_bytes, image_obj);
jbyteArray arr = static_cast<jbyteArray>(arr_obj);

//my needed result
unsigned char myArr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char>(arr);
```

**EDIT**

```
jbyteArray arr_obj = (jbyteArray) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.get_bytes, image_obj);
```

Now I have jbyteArray... but anyway I don't understand how with using of `GetByteArrayElements` get my `byte[]` into my var `unsigned char *i_image`?

**EDIT**

```
jbyteArray arr_obj = (jbyteArray)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.get_bytes, image_obj);
jbyte *b = (jbyte *) env->GetByteArrayElements(arr_obj, NULL);
i_image = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(b);
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(arr_obj, b, JNI_ABORT);
```

Comment: I do not know NDK or JNI, but as a `byte[]` is an `Object`, why not use `CallStaticObjectMethod`?

Comment: You can't cast `arr` to `unsigned char` like that. You need to use `GetByteArrayElements` (and `ReleaseByteArrayElements`). Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: @Michael I edited my question. jbyteArray arr_obj = (jbyteArray) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.get_bytes, image_obj); Now I have jbyteArray... but anyway I don't understand how with using of GetByteArrayElements get my byte[] into my var unsigned char *i_image?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to? `unsigned char*` is exactly what `GetByteArrayElements` will return (actually it will return `jbyte*`, which is a typedef for `char*`, but you can cast that to `unsigned char*`). There are plenty of examples here on StackOverflow for how to access Java arrays through JNI. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724022/jni-jiniarray-as-output-parameter-doesnt-change-values-of-parameter/54724453#54724453) which does the same thing but for an `int[]`.

Comment: @Michael yes, I read but I am not sure that I understood clearly... I edited my question, do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, except the pointer is no longer valid after you call `ReleaseByteArrayElements`. So you should release the array after you're done using the pointer. Also, if you only intend to read from the array you may want to pass `JNI_ABORT` to `ReleaseByteArrayElements` instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp9502), byte arrays are not primitive types, they are objects.
As such, you need to use `CallStaticObjectMethod`.

The result type will be `jobject`, but you can safely cast this to `jbyteArray` (if it is not `null`, of course).
With the `jbyteArray` in hand you can call `GetByteArrayElements` or `GetByteArrayRegion`.

Comment: I edited my question. jbyteArray arr_obj = (jbyteArray) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.get_bytes, image_obj); Now I have jbyteArray... but anyway I don't understand how with using of GetByteArrayElements get my byte[] into my var unsigned char *i_image?